# React Native. I have just started learning react native and I have a question about return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a question about return statement.There is a return already wrapped whole code why are we returning  again?Why there are two return in this code? Thanks for your help.

````
return (
    <FlatList
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      keyExtractor={(friend) => friend.name}
      data={friends}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
       return <Text style={styles.text}>
          {item.name} - Age: {item.Age}
        </Text>;
      }}
    />
  );```
````

Comment: second return it is kind of inline arrow function for render item. You could move that code out of method in separate function and have renderItem={yourFunction()}

Comment: Please read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem) for the `renderItem` prop on a `FlatList`, you'll see that it is expecting a function. That return statement is part of that function.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, you can't find something conclusive about the why.. But you can look into [Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem) and see that it expects to return a React Element.

Also, if you look into the source itself you can see that the return statement exists because of the iteration:

[image]

Since the `Data` attribute aways expect an array:

[image]

Your `renderItem` should iterate it for each ocurrence and return the Reat Element